# Databricks Notebook returning the same random value

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am trying to experiment in adding new columns to dataframes but whenever I try grab dataTime.now() or as below use a random number then it always returns the same value unless I stop the Notebook and start it again. Not sure why this is occurring am fairly new to Databricks

```
def create_random():
  return random()
```

I also tried this function but always seems to grab the initial date time but never updates it beyond that:

```
def create_random():
  now = datetime.now()
  return(now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
  


newEventStream = streamingEvents.withColumn("loadTime", lit(create_random()))
```

Comment: "always returns the same value" - isn't this exactly what `seed(1)` is supposed to do? It fixes the random seed to a constant

Comment: I used pyspark.sql.functions.current_timestamp() and that worked rather than dateTime, some how it must of been caching the value

Answer (score 2):

A seed() is used to deterministically produce the same random value on subsequent runs. Remove that line.

Comment: Hello sorry this did not solve the issue, I believe its probably to do with how Databricks Notebook is operating, have also updated my question to make it clearer

Comment: Is the problem that you are trying to produce a different random value per row and right now its the same for the whole column? Or is the problem that every time you run the cell with the random function it produces the same random value for every row?